# Grouping Object with certain field using Java Collectors.toMap

Tags: java

I want to group Person objects base on gender with  `Collectors.toMap()`  function as describe below, but this does not work as I expected.

```
class Person{
   private Integer id;
   private String gender;
   private String name;
   public String getGender(){
       return gender;
   }
   public Person(Integer id, String gender, String name){
       this.id=id;
       this.gender=gender;
       this.name=name;    
   }
}


public static void main(String[]args){
   List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();
   persons.add(new Person(1,"Man","John"));
   persons.add(new Person(2,"Man","Steve"));
   persons.add(new Person(3,"Women","Linda"));
   persons.add(new Person(4,"Man","Bill"));
   persons.add(new Person(5,"Women","Siti"));
   persons.add(new Person(6,"Man","Buzzer"));

   Map<String,List<Person>> filtered=persons
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person:getGender:Function.identity()));

}
```

Error hint

> incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: List
> lower bounds: Person,T#2,T#1
> where U,T#1,K,T#2 are type-variables:
> U extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? > > extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U>)
> T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? > extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U>)
> K extends Object declared in method <T#1,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T#1,? >
> extends K>,Function<? super T#1,? extends U>)
> T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>identity()

> type of <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>) is erroneous
> where R,A,T are type-variables:
> R extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
> A extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)

Can someone explain this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
final var filtered = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```

Comment: this work but i wonder when add forEach((gender,p)->{ System.out.println(gender};); this work

Answer (score 0):

`Collectors.toMap()` isn't that good for what you want to do. Instead try out `Collectors.groupingBy()`.

```
Map<String,List<Person>> filtered = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```

Comment: @magicom, so Collectors.groupingBy best what for?

Comment: Well `groupingBy` is as the name suggest best for grouping stuff. So you have one key and multiple values. `toMap` is much simpler and just accepts two functions to create your key and value.